# Matlab: How can I draw on an image and use what I draw as segmentation seeds?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to draw structures of interest in MRI to implement a variant of the GrowCut algorithm. What's the simple way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: What do you have? An image? Data? If it's the latter, how is it formatted? What is the desired output? More details would be appreciated!

Comment: MRI = Magnetic Resonance Imaging, so it's images. The desired output is segmented anatomical structures.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GrowCut_algorithm

Comment: Deleted my answer. For clarification, you should specify in your question that you want freehand drawing on an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone at MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/58000-how-can-i-draw-on-an-image-and-use-what-i-draw-as-segmentation-seeds) suggested me to [use imfreehand](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/building-guis-with-modular-interactive-tools.html) and I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

For free hand drawing over an image [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7347) is a file from Matlab File exchange...

Hope it solves your problem...